# Verb describing the readying of the hammer of a gun

Tags: word-request, verbs

Before pulling the trigger, we must ready the gun's hammer, if it has one.

What is the verb describing this action, i.e., the action of rotating the gun's hammer to make it ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is [*cock*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cock) (meaning 12 in the reference)